# Where to buy (carbon) framesets?

Tags: frames, build, shopping

I'm looking for online suppliers of carbon road framesets, the major online retailers [Wiggle](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/cycle/frames/carbon-frame-material/?s=frameset), [Evanscycles](http://www.evanscycles.com/search?fh_eds%5B%5D=%C3%9F&fh_location%5B%5D=%2F%2Fproducts%2Fen_GB%2Favailable_in%3E%7Bgb%7D%2F%24s%3Dframeset%2Fframe_material%3E%7Bcarbon%7D&fh_reffacet%5B%5D=frame_material&fh_refpath%5B%5D=facet_16&fh_refview%5B%5D=search&fh_view_size%5B%5D=21&query=frameset&x=0&y=0) and [Chainreactioncycles](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/se/en/s?q=frameset&f=4294966775) don't seem to have much choice available (~<10 each) with low diversity in brands.

What other (reputable) suppliers are present in the online market that have a large range of products to chose from? Or do framesets tend to be bought directly from the manufacturer?

I ask because most brands are missing entirely and some (e.g. Specialized) only have one or two of their frames available through these sites, yet they don't sell them directly, therefore I think I'm not looking in the right places. (I am based in Sweden if you want to limit it to Europe/European delivery)

Comment: Voting to close - too opinion based, and highly specific to the market you are in (for example, On One sells different framesets in the UK and the US).

Comment: I've been told that most carbon frames come from just a couple of factories, and furthermore that only the largest bike companies even use their own moulds. This doesn't necessarily help you but it might go some way to explaining why your problem exists. I agree with @Batman but to try and help you....I think people in the UK like Ribble Cycles and PlanetX take generic frames and brand them. They might be able to help you.

Comment: @peteH thanks for the tips. & to the close voters: I don't see how this is an opinion based question, I'm asking what suppliers there are for carbon framesets. *It can not be an opinion that a supplier sells carbon framesets*, it is either true or false, they either *do* or *do not* sell carbon framesets. I've listed three suppliers that are missing a number of the big-brand frame manufacturers and sought clarification of where to find brand name frames online.

Comment: Well, the "opinion based" typically covers shopping questions since there isn't something closer to shopping questions. At least in the US, the big 3 (Trek, Specialized and Giant) don't allow their complete bikes to be sold online - only through bike shops. I'd suspect the same is true of their frame sets.

Comment: @Batman and GriffinEvo The off-topic/shopping closure specifically mentions service recommendations as part of the closure criteria. As such, I've closed this question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, I think I may have misunderstood your original question.

Most bike shops I know seem to be "licensed resellers" for just a couple of brands. My local shop, for example, stocks only Bianchi and Specialized. If I want to buy a Trek I need to go someplace else. A lot of web sites in the cycling business (certainly in the UK) are basically virtual fronts for bricks-and-mortar shops, so it doesn't really surprise me that when you go to a particular web site, you don't see a broad range of brands.

To be honest, if you are looking for a branded frame, your best approach might be to go in the other direction. Find the frame that you like, then find a dealer (either locally or through a web site). You might need a dealer's help in any case if you're looking just for a frame rather than a complete bike. But e.g. Bianchi offer frames on their site, so presumably someone, somewhere will sell you one!

In my comment I mentioned a couple of bike shops who (I think) have brought in generic carbon frames and built and branded them. That route may also be an option.